# React component fails to update onClick event handler

Tags: javascript, onclick, requirejs, reactjs

I have a react component which represents a row in a table of words. It re-renders when the state changes, but it does not update `onClick` event handler.  I have stripped down the component to the bare minimum and it still has the issue. When I click the "Edit" link, the console prints "onEdit" and the state appears to look correct in the browser, but then when I click "Revert", the console prints "onEdit" a second time.  Why is the `onClick` event not being updated to use the `_onRevert` function after the state changes? Why it is still hanging on to the old event handler from the first render pass? Thank you.

```
var React = require('React/addons');

var WordListItem = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            isEditing: false,
            english: this.props.word.english
        };
    },
    _onEdit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('onEdit');
        this.setState({isEditing: true});
    },
    _onRevert: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('onRevert');
        this.setState({isEditing: false});
    },
    render: function() {
        if(this.state.isEditing) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <span>Editing: {this.state.english} </span>
                    <a href="#" onClick={this._onRevert}>Revert</a>
                </div>
            )
        } else {

            return (
                <div>
                    <span>Not Editing: {this.state.english} </span>
                    <a href="#" onClick={this._onEdit}>Edit</a>
                </div>
            )
        }

    }
})

module.exports = WordListItem;
```

**UPDATE BELOW**

So it turns out that it works if I paste this component into my main app.jsx file, it works, but not if I include it using require js. Which is weird, because browserify is working since I can still include other files and compose nested react components, it just that it the events don't get updated on some elements. Maybe at this point I should ask a new question, which is more focused.

```
    var React = require('react/addons');
//var materialize = require('materialize-css');
var word = {id: 4671810846, english: "water", persian: "آب", phonetic: "aab", tags: ["noun","food","drink"]};

var WordListItem = require('./components/wordList/WordListItem.jsx');

// var WordListItem = React.createClass({
//     getInitialState: function(){
//         return {
//             isEditing: false,
//             english: this.props.word.english
//         };
//     },
//     _onEdit: function(e) {
//         e.preventDefault();
//         console.log('onEdit');
//         this.setState({isEditing: true});
//     },
//     _onRevert: function(e){
//         e.preventDefault();
//         console.log('onRevert');
//         this.setState({isEditing: false});
//     },
//     render: function() {
//         if(this.state.isEditing) {
//             return (
//                 <div>
//                     <span>Editing: {this.state.english} </span>
//                     <a href="#" onClick={this._onRevert}>Revert</a>
//                 </div>
//             )
//         } else {
//
//             return (
//                 <div>
//                     <span>Not Editing: {this.state.english} </span>
//                     <a href="#" onClick={this._onEdit}>Edit</a>
//                 </div>
//             )
//         }
//
//     }
// })


React.render(<WordListItem word={word}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: console.log "this" inside of the function call for _onEdit, and then console.log the state of isEditing. Are you sure your context is correct inside of that function?

Comment: Well that is interesting. When I log `this` and click Edit and then click Revert, both _onEdit and _onRevert handlers log the same `this` object, and the state of isEditing is set to true inside this object. However, this.state.isEditing first prints false, and then it prints true.

Comment: well, at least there's the real issue. Your code works, but it looks like the inital state is getting set again.

Comment: I put a print statement in the getInitialState function, and it only gets called once for each copy of this component and never gets called again, even after clicking the links.

Comment: The code you've posted seems to work fine as-is; see http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/3zeb0gdo/ I also see alternating `console.log`s of "onEdit" and "onRevert", as expected.

Comment: The code works fine.

Comment: i can confirm this issue when rendering this as a child of another component. It works fine when its the top level component just like the fiddle above

Comment: Thank you everyone for showing that the component works in isolation. It must be something wrong with the parent component. At least I know where to look now.

Comment: I updated the question above. Essentially, the component works when I pasted into the main app.jsx, but not if I use requireJS and a second file.

Comment: In your word_list_item.jsx file, you require react as var React = require('React/addons'); Is this just a typo you made when you were pasting code ? It should be var React = require('react/addons') with lower case letters. Just a small observation, not sure if this has to do with anything, but sure looks like you have some kind of browserify issue.

Comment: I have several react components, each in their own file, and it works (mostly).  If there was a problem with typos in path names, I would get undefined variable errors, but this is not the case, I just get weird behaviour where a component doesn't update probably on re-render.

Comment: Holy Moly, @blushrt, that was the answer! when I had `var React = require('React/addons');` it fails but  `var React = require('react/addons')` works!  That is so bizarre.  Thank you for spotting that!

Comment: Np :) Glad it helped. Sometimes typos can be a b*, especially in javascript land.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the way you are rendering this child component in a parent ? I have a suspicion that when you are generating an array of WordListItem's you are not setting a key property (or using a simple index as key property, which is a recipe for disaster if you are also removing WordListItem's, the key has to be unique.

Also i think this component would be better if it didn't have state at all, have state on top parent component instead and send props down to children.

EDIT:

In your word_list_item.jsx file, you require react as var React = require('React/addons'); Is this just a typo you made when you were pasting code ? It should be var React = require('react/addons') with lower case letters. Just a small observation, not sure if this has to do with anything, but sure looks like you have some kind of browserify issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I definitely set a unique key in a list of them. Also, the state is useful, just maybe not for this stripped down version.